# Query to Return Machine Running Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that stores the active power of a generator:

```
     TimeStamp           ActivePower
2020-12-05  11:00:00        1200
2020-12-05  11:05:00        1250
2020-12-05  11:10:00        1300
2020-12-05  11:15:00        0
2020-12-05  11:20:00        0
2020-12-05 11:25:00        1300
....
```

I would like to make a query that returns the total time the machine was running, that is, the power greater than 0.

My situation is similar to that described in this topic [(Determine time between transitions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575244/determine-on-time-between-1-to-0-transitions), but as my condition is not Boolean I was unable to adapt the code.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not similar. You're looking to identify the *islands* in the data where `ActivePower` isn't zero. This type of problem is called the `gaps & islands` problem

Comment: What results do you want?  How do you define "running"?

Comment: Running machine means active power greater than zero. @PanagiotisKanavos the question is similar. We can consider active power greater than 0 as 1, and the other situation as 0.

The answers below helped to solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: @FelipeFonsecabh the answers helped because they identify the islands of non-0 power. Especially Popeye's which returns 0 for a gap (even calls it lgap) and 1 for an island. Both use `LEAD` to find the next value in the island and calculate the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
select sum(datediff(minute, min(timestamp), max(timestamp))) as total_up_time
  from (select t.*, 
               sum(case when lgap = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
                    over (order by timestamp) as sm
          from (select t.*,
                       lag(activepower) over (order by timestamp) as lgap
                  from your_Table t
               ) t
       ) t group by sm
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just need `lead()` and some date arithmetic.  That would be:

```
select sum(datediff(minute, timestamp, next_timestamp)) as total_minutes_active
from (select t.*,
             lead(timestamp) over (order by timestamp) as next_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
where activepower > 0;
```

This adds up the minutes (or whatever) between a row and the next row, when `activepower > 0`.